# Select Date from DatePicker using Selenium Webriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker, automated-tests

Here is my code :

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("fromdate")).click();
    List<WebElement> allDates=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//td"));

    String ee = String.valueOf(i);
    for(WebElement ele:allDates)
    {
        String date=ele.getText();
        if(date.equalsIgnoreCase(ee)) 
        {
            ele.click();
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        System.out.println(i);
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}
```

I want to select date from "1" to date "5" (By a loop), so that further i can apply this loop to select from date "1" to "current date".

Comment: Can you give me the site url?

Comment: It is easy to understand if you provide url or html code for the calender element

Comment: Actually the URL on local server of my company ..... May be it will not open on your system ... still it is 172.20.5.3/bo

Comment: what is the issue? where is the html code of the date picket, what you mean by you want to click 1 to 5, is it multi select, where you can select multiple dates.

Comment: I want to select date 1 till 5 i.e. firstly , date 1 is selected and then it should select date 2 and so on . but here loop is not working

Comment: driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/");
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/a[1]/span")).click();
 WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-datepicker-div"));
 List<WebElement> allDates= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//td"));
  for (WebElement ele : allDates) {
   String date = ele.getText();
   for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    String ee = String.valueOf(i);
    if (date.equalsIgnoreCase(ee)) {
     ele.click();
    }}}

Comment: In above code , i provided the URL , i want this loop for "i" to work for dates 1 to 5

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code is working fine :

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
String a = (dateFormat.format(date));
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

int dates = localDate.getDayOfMonth();

String t[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" ,"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"," 24", "25", for (int i = 0; i <= dates - 3; i++) {
driver.findElement(By.id("drawdate")).click();
WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-datepicker-div"));
List<WebElement> allDates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//td"));

for (WebElement ele : allDates) {
String datee = ele.getText();
if (datee.equalsIgnoreCase(t[i]) && !datee.equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {
ele.click();
Thread.sleep(500);
break;
}
```

}

I got the solution of my problem , now i can select all dates from calender till today's date from first date of month.